# Azure DevOps API: how can I get list of commits between tags, when tag name contains a folder?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to get the list of commits in our project between 2 annotated tags.

If my tags are without folder, I managed to do it with this code:

```
string preiousVersionTag = "tag 1";
string currentVersionTag = "tag 2";
string projectID = "My GUID for project ID";
string ORG = "My_ORG";

NameValueCollection queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
queryString.Add("itemVersion.version", preiousVersionTag);
queryString.Add("itemVersion.versionType", "tag");
queryString.Add("compareVersion.version", currentVersionTag);
queryString.Add("compareVersion.versionType", "tag");
queryString.Add("includeWorkItems", "true");

string parameters = queryString.ToString();
string requestUri = $"/{Org}/_apis/git/repositories/{projectID}/commits?api-version=6.0&{parameters}";


HttpClient httpClient = CreateOAuthHttpClient(tokenModel.AccessToken);
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);


string resultContent = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();



private static HttpClient CreateOAuthHttpClient(string accessToken)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = CreateHttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    return httpClient;
}
```

My problem starts when my tags are organized under folders, and then the API call returns no results.
I tried sending tag ID instead of name but got 404 return.

Any advice?